# Evaluating an optimal control problem numerically with unrestricted final time

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, optimal-control

I have an optimal control problem as follows:

Minimize

$\int_{0}^{t_f}dt$

Where the state equations are

$\frac{dr}{dt} = v$ 
 
$\frac{dv}{dt} = -\frac{1}{r^2} + cos(u) + \frac{r}{\omega^2}$ 
 
$\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \omega$ 
 
$\frac{d\omega}{dt} = \frac{sin(u) - 2v\omega}{r}$

Subject to initial conditions 
$r(0) = R$ 
$v(0) =  0$ 
$\theta(0) = 0$ 
$\omega(0) =  0$

and final conditions 
$r(t_f) = R'$ 
$v(t_f) = 0$ 
$\theta(t_f) = \theta'$ 
$\omega(t_f) = \omega'$

Where
$u = u(t)$
is the control function, and where $R, R', \theta', \omega'$ are constant and are to be specified by a given situation.

My question revolves around solving this problem numerically given the nature of $t_f$ being free. I have constructed the Hamiltonian and found the co-state differential equations, and have even been able to find that $u(t) = \tan^{-1}(\frac{z_4}{z_2})$ where $z_4$ and $z_2$ are co-state equations. However, I don't know how to go about solving this numerically. I would assume a shooting method would be useful where one changes the initial conditions for the co-state differential equations which determine $u$ and continue shooting until the final condition at $t_f$ are satisfied. The problem is I don't know how to take into consideration that $t_f$ is free as the shooting method heavily depends on this being fixed. From all my reading I haven't been able to find any clues as to how to numerically solve this problem given that $t_f$ is free.

Any help would be appreciated.